# How to organize random spatial data for an area of interest?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, environmental-monitoring

I'm trying to take a huge amount of spatial data for a specific 200,000 acre area, collected over 15 years dating back to 2000, and organize it. The data layers relate to wildfires, habitat rehabilitation efforts, biology, vegetation etc.

The goal is that for any point (or tract of land) within this area, the vegetation/monitoring/wildfire/etc history could be easily accessed, without having a unwieldy mxd full of layers to navigate through.

Is there a method or general framework to organize large amounts of spatial data for a particular area of interest?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: Data automation has taken impressive strides over the years, but reorganizing a mess of data to be intuitive for human use is not a current capability.

Comment: There is no substitute for hard work. How do you intend to wield this data in the end? It would be fine to say "union it into a single layer" but we both know that's just going to make more of a mess. I think it would be better to have some sort of tool that for a point/area interrogates the existing data and returns what it finds... you have an arcpy tag, would you be proficient enough to write an add-in?

Comment: Thank you for the input. In the end I'd like to be able to access, with as few steps as possible, the environmental management history for any point or area within the boundary of 200,000 acres. I have hardly any Python experience, but I put the tag because I figured it might be useful. What is an "add-in" and how could it apply here? Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not a automation problem, but rather a manual organizational problem. Unfortunately, there is not a single answer, although there is a general framework you can follow for this common problem. Creating a massively complex .mxd file is not the answer here. Instead, pull up only the data you need for your particular analyses. I see two major priorities that you need to sort out:

1. Ensure all spatial data are in the same projected coordinate system.
2. All categories of data need to be in the same location (e.g.
   wetlands, wildfire locations, etc)

I would begin by creating a file geodatabase to store your vector data. Inside the file geodatabase, create feature datasets (FDS) with a projected coordinate system that suites your needs. Create as many or as few feature datasets as needed to organize your data. Sometimes it is handy to create a single feature dataset named, for example, "utm15" indicating that all data contained within have a utm 15 projected coordinate system. Other times, it may be handy to create multiple feature datasets such as "wetlands", "wildfires", etc. In any event, any spatial data you import into the feature dataset will be projected to whichever PCS you assigned to the FDS.

If you use raster data for any type of analysis, I would keep the raster data in an open format such as TIFF or IMG to ensure compatibility with non-Esri software. However, if you only need to store raster data to use as basemaps, then creating mosaic datasets in a file geodatabase can be handy.